# sending mail in Laravel 5.4 using Mailgun get error code " 401 UNAUTHORIZED` response: Forbidden "

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun

I'm trying to send mail in Laravel 5.4 project with Mailgun. I think I set the configuration correctly. But, I got this error message such as

> ClientException in RequestException.php line 111:
>   Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxfeb88d58f18841738b2fc81d7cbc7631.mailgun.org/messages.mime` >resulted in a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response:
>   Forbidden

Here is my configuration:

in .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandboxfeb88d58f18841738b2fc81d7cbc7631.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=pubkey-1767e**********
```

in mail.php file

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'richi.htoo@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Richi Htoo'),
],
```

in services.php file

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

and I wrote mail sending code in default route such as

```
Route::get('/', function () {
//return view('welcome');

    $data = [
        'title' => 'Hi student I hope you like the course',
        'content' => 'This laravel course was created with a lot of love and dedication for you'
    ];

    Mail::send('emails.test', $data, function($message){
        $message->to('white.nuzzle@gmail.com', 'White Nuzzle')->subject('Hello student how are you?');
    });
});
```

And I also installed Laravel Package "guzzlehttp/guzzle" version 6.2 to send mail.

But when I call that default home route, I got an error message as I mention above.

I can't find any solution for my error in any where including this forum "stackoverflow.com".

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Its a very very late. But You are using wrong key MAILGUN_SECRET= Must be Secret Key not public key. 
I was facing same problem and figured it out. :p

Comment: If you are not using the United States as your region, that may be the problem.

Answer (score 12):

Ok found it,
In the file "vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Transport\MailgunTransport.php", the endpoint used is US one.

As said in documentation, https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-intro.html#mailgun-regions, you have an endpoint for US and EU.

If you are european, you must use "api.eu.mailgun.net" or you get a 401.

Just change the endpoint: Laravel is powerful and they think about that. You can add an 'endpoint' key to the config/services.php/mailgun entry.

Comment: Thank you! Would spend several more hours if it were not for your post.

Answer (score 11):

If you are not using the United States Mailgun region, you can define your region's endpoint in the services configuration file:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.eu.mailgun.net'),
],
```

Alternatively, one can define the MAILGUN_ENDPOINT in the .env file:

```
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT="api.eu.mailgun.net"
```

Comment: This helped me regarding the European region.  Thank you.  It should be stated that you can also just add MAILGUN_ENDPOINT='api.eu.mailgun.net' to your .env file.

Comment: thanks, that helped me too, I'm using node.js but had the similar issue :D

Answer (score 10):

Frankly it was quite an ordeal, I made the sandbox work as following

1. Added authorized recipient - Apparently sandbox can't send email to
   anyone, you need to add them as authorized recipient.
2. Use proper credentials in .env File added `MAILGUN_DOMAIN` and `MAILGUN_SECRET` too as services.php uses them. Remember `MAILGUN_SECRET` is the private key and starts with `key-`, don't use public key here
3. Put
   `MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org MAIL_PORT=587 MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@sandboxcc*****************.mailgun.org MAIL_PASSWORD=****************** MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`
4. ***!!!MOST IMPORTANT!!!! RESTART YOUR SERVER to load the new .env file***.

Comment: I did not have to do step 1 but that's probably because I'm not using a sandbox in my case.

Comment: Using the private API key is what did it for me. Using Laravel 6.9.0, but just set `MAIL_DRIVER` to `mailgun`, and added the `MAILGUN_DOMAIN` and `MAILGUN_SECRET` lines to my `.env` file and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to check your credentials for the mailgun, make sure that those are correct.

Dont copy the Public Validation Key. 
please copy the Private API Key

Comment: To me this answer helped, somehow my Mailgun's private key was different. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I just want to summarize what I had to do to make `Mailgun` work in `Laravel 8`.

## **1. Install guzzle**

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

## **2. EU or US?**

I'm from EU. The Laravel Doc for Mailgun says to configure mailgun for usage in EU. This is WRONG if you're using the `sandbox` because it is located in the `US` apparently. I have a small `US flag` next to my `sandbox url` and it took me ages to figure this out.

If you want to use the `sandbox` put this into **`\config\services.php`**:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'),
],
```

If you want to use a domain that is registered for `EU` you will need to make this change:

```
'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.eu.mailgun.net'),
```

If you put the wrong region, your `log` should throw `401 UNAUTHORIZED response`

## **3. Authorize Recipients**

If you're using the `sandbox` you need to authorize recipients. Go to your mailgun account and to your `sandbox domain` and authorize recipients in the email field. If you try to send an email to non-authorized recipients your `log` should throw an `403 FORBIDDEN response`

## **4. Default Mailer**

If you want `mailgun` to be your default mailer you can change this in your **`\config\mail.php`**:

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'mailgun'),
```

## **5. Credentials**

These credentials made it work for me, hopefully they will make it work for you too. Put them in **`.env`**:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandboxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=2dfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

`MAILGUN_SECRET` is your `private api key` which can be found when go to your mailgun account and click on your `profile logo -> api keys`.

`MAILGUN_DOMAIN` is your (I believe currently used) domain and can be accessed in your mailgun account either through the `dashboard` or through `sending->domains` in the navpanel. The only not messy reference field for your domain seems to be in `sending->overview-> select SMTP` and copy the end part of the `Username` field (without `postmaster@`)

I hope this saves time for someone because it took forever to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Default Mail Driver: Mailgun

```
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=*your-domain*.mailgun.org

MAILGUN_SECRET=pubkey-*your-public-key*
```

Default Mail Driver: SMTP

```
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@*your-domain*.mailgun.org

MAIL_PASSWORD=*your-password*
```

Don't forget to `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Check your DNS settings in the Mailgun Sending domain checklist. I found I could not get an EU MG setting to work so I suggest you use a US MG server

Answer (score 0):

Personally I never got the sandbox account to work. I just did this a little over a month ago. Sandbox never worked, but the live account I created did. Try switching to the live account and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hello, my friend Fastmover. I have no domain. I'm just testing to send mail in my tutorial exercise. So, can you suggest me other way please. By the way thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: Might have to contact mailgun's support about the sandbox account.  I'm not sure there.

Comment: @WhiteNuzzle you can create sandbox account free of charge. And if you want to test with that account you have to first **invite recipients** (Authorized Recipients). one more thing first time when you receive the mail most of the time it will be appear in spam/junk box

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the config folder. and made some changes..

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('your_domainxxxxxxx.mailgun.org'),
    'secret' => env('key-xxxxxxxx_private_API_keyxxxx'),
],
```

error will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you use API base mailgun, check if the **domain exists**.
I removed my testing domain and after it tried to send a new email message from that domain. I got 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Symfony. Yes, it's not Laravel but they're close.

In `.env` file I had

`MAILER_DSN=mailgun://KEY:DOMAIN@default`

The error disappeared after I changed it to

`MAILER_DSN=mailgun://KEY:DOMAIN@default?region=eu`