# POST request in Laravel 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: laravel, email, guzzle

I have following error when try to send mail from Laravel 7 using mailgun driver.

```
Client error: `POST https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mail.firstdomain.com/messages.mime` resulted in a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response: Forbidden
C:\laragon\www\lara7\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php#113
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
```

It was working before and I don't remember at which point error appeared.

Before I got one problem with mailgun. It was like I see in debugbar that mail is sent, but then it is not delivered to recepient.
And problem was that FROM field was empty and in mailgun account those messages were located  in BOUNCE list without movement.
Now there is nothing blocked at mailgun side. I think they are blocked somewhere inside Laravel.

Here is my code

**routes\web.php**

```
Route::post('/mymail', 'MainController@mymail')->name('mymail');
```

**.env**

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@firstdomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="robot name"
MAIL_TO_ADDRESS=user@seconddomain.com
MAIL_TO_NAME="TO name"
MAIL_REPLY_TO_ADDRESS=abc@seconddomain.com
MAIL_REPLY_TO_NAME="my name"
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mail.firstdomain.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=mysecret
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.eu.mailgun.net
```

**config\mail.php*

```
    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'mailgun'),
    'mailers' => [
        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
    'to' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_TO_ADDRESS'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_TO_NAME'),
    ],
    'reply_to' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_REPLY_TO_ADDRESS'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME')
    ],
```

**App\Http\Controllers\MainController.php*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\Mymail;
use App\Http\Requests\MymailRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MainController extends Controller
{

    public function mymail(MymailRequest $request) {

        Mail::to( 'user@seconddomain.com' )->send(new Mymail());
        return [
            'message' => 'Sent!', 
                ];
    }
}
```

**App\Mail\Mymail.php**

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\MymailRequest;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Mymail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject = 'My test mail';

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function build(MymailRequest $request)
    {
        $this->from('noreply@firstdomain.com')->view('mail.mymail')->withRequest($request);
    }
}
```

**App\Http\Requests\MymailRequest.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MymailRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required'

        ];
    }
}
```

**resources\views\mail\mymail.blade.php**

```
<p>{{ $request->currentUrl }}</p>
<p>{{ $request->name }}</p>
<p>{{ $request->phone }}</p>
```

Here is  response from chrome dev tools network tab

```
{
    "message": "Client error: `POST https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mail.firstdomain.com/messages.mime` resulted in a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response:\nForbidden\n",
    "exception": "GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ClientException",
    "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Exception\\RequestException.php",
    "line": 113,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Middleware.php",
            "line": 65,
            "function": "create",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\promises\\src\\Promise.php",
            "line": 203,
            "function": "GuzzleHttp\\{closure}",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Middleware",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\promises\\src\\Promise.php",
            "line": 156,
            "function": "callHandler",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\promises\\src\\TaskQueue.php",
            "line": 47,
            "function": "GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\{closure}",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\promises\\src\\Promise.php",
            "line": 246,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\TaskQueue",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\promises\\src\\Promise.php",
            "line": 223,
            "function": "invokeWaitFn",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\promises\\src\\Promise.php",
            "line": 267,
            "function": "waitIfPending",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\promises\\src\\Promise.php",
            "line": 225,
            "function": "invokeWaitList",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\promises\\src\\Promise.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "waitIfPending",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Client.php",
            "line": 183,
            "function": "wait",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Transport\\MailgunTransport.php",
            "line": 72,
            "function": "request",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Client",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Mailer.php",
            "line": 71,
            "function": "send",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Transport\\MailgunTransport",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer.php",
            "line": 519,
            "function": "send",
            "class": "Swift_Mailer",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer.php",
            "line": 288,
            "function": "sendSwiftMessage",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable.php",
            "line": 170,
            "function": "send",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Traits\\Localizable.php",
            "line": 19,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Mail\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "withLocale",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer.php",
            "line": 304,
            "function": "send",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailable",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer.php",
            "line": 258,
            "function": "sendMailable",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\PendingMail.php",
            "line": 122,
            "function": "send",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\MainController.php",
            "line": 48,
            "function": "send",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Mail\\PendingMail",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "function": "freezamer",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\MainController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "call_user_func_array"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php",
            "line": 45,
            "function": "callAction",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
            "line": 225,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
            "line": 182,
            "function": "runController",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 685,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php",
            "line": 41,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php",
            "line": 76,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php",
            "line": 56,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
            "line": 37,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php",
            "line": 66,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 687,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 662,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 628,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 617,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 165,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\barryvdh\\laravel-debugbar\\src\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar.php",
            "line": 65,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 63,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php",
            "line": 37,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 140,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 109,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\laragon\\www\\lara7\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `I think they are blocked somewhere inside Laravel` - why do you think that? `401` is coming from the remote API, right?  There are some duplicates of your error msg here, do they help? Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415563/sending-mail-in-laravel-5-4-using-mailgun-get-error-code-401-unauthorized-res

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but FYI your configured `reply_to` `name` looks wrong - you're not using the `MAIL_REPLY_TO_NAME` you've set up in `.env`.  You didn't show us what `env('APP_NAME')` is, but even if it is blank I guess it should work.

Comment: `APP_NAME="my host name"`

Answer (score 0):

As per Mailgun documentation: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-intro.html#errors

> 401   Unauthorized - No valid API key provided

Make sure that you are using valid API key - or sending to registered email addresses if you are using Sandbox.

Comment: No valid API key provided - is not possible, because I just copied all mailgun settings from another laravel installation. I have 2 lara projects on one PC now with the same mailgun settings in env file. From one project I can send mail easily and from another I got 401 error.

Comment: Are you using the same domain for both projects?

Comment: In mailgun I have only one domain registered. So on both projects I use absolutely the same settings. But I don't think mailgun can distinguish them as different applications, because they are located on one local PC.

Answer (score 0):

Try after whitelisting your servers IP:

```
Mailgun Dashboard > Settings > API Keys > API Security IP Whitelist
```

Once added, it may take a few minutes to become active, after which you should be able to send emails from your laravel app