# Unable to send an email: Forbidden (code 401) Heroku Laravel Mailgun Error

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, recaptcha, mailgun

I added all env configs but am still gettings this error:

**"Unable to send an email: Forbidden (code 401) Heroku Laravel Mailgun Error"**

My Mailgun successfully works on localhost but when deployed on Heroku it stops working.

Configs in .env:

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandboxa0575477a07c4d46bc474dfd7d104316.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=6fb8c8fdbd262ef08ff062388c8cb9f4-02fa25a3-ff2ddce5
```

Configs for mail..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415563/sending-mail-in-laravel-5-4-using-mailgun-get-error-code-401-unauthorized-res

Comment: Didn't help bro. I tried before asking.

Comment: set `MAIL_MAILER=mailgun` to `MAIL_MAILER=smtp` and try again

Comment: Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add these lines of code inside your .env file:

MAIL_MAILER=mailgun

MAIL_MAILER=smtp